# SSRS - Uninstall Trial Version of VS Business Intelligence

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

I want to know how to fully uninstall `MSSQL 2005`.

I've been using the Trial version of SQL Server Reporting Services for a while now.   My company finally purchased the software from an online distributor, and for support of Oracle, we needed to upgrade to MSSQL 2005 SP2.   Anyway, the "full" version of the software would not install, as it was already installed (It seems the installer doesn't recognize what was installed was the trial version).   So I tried uninstalling MSSQL 2005, and everything related (including visual studio), I can not seem to get it reinstalled.   The error is a vague error message, and when i click the link to get more information, the usual "no information about this error was found" error.

> ### Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Setup
>
> There was an unexpected failure during
>   the setup wizard. You may review the
>   setup logs and/or click the help
>   button for more information.
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=9.00.1399.06&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&EvtType=packageengine%5cinstallpackageaction.cpp%40InstallToolsAction.11%40sqls%3a%3aInstallPackageAction%3a%3aperform%400x643
>
> ### BUTTONS:
>
> OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mark Struzinski

I actually discovered that it was a problem with the installer, when installing the "Full Version".   I discovered, since the product was downloaded, instead of delivered on CD/DVD, that the installer was looking for information in a path that was not correct.    There was a MS Knowledge Base article on the topic.    Thanks for your reply, tho

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, and this article helped me clean up all the related files from my system and do a fresh install of both Visual Studio and the SQL client components. Give it a try and let me know if it helps you out:

http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX115270